# Does self-defined headers count as preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

All the statements with the symbol `#` are known as preprocessor directive. My question is does self-defined headers count as preprocessor directive?

```
# include "example.cpp" // Does it count as preprocessor directive
```

or is it only the header file defined by programmers allowed to be (called) a preprocessor directive?

Comment: Everything that starts with # is a preprocessor directive.

Comment: And in particular, any line starting with `#include` is a preprocessor directive.

Comment: Yes, why not? Note that "the file" is not a directive. `#include` followed by a file name is.

Comment: the #include is the preprocessor directive.  The bit that follows is the file that will be pasted into this file that is then compiled into an object.

Comment: I should mention that it is not a good idea to include a `.cpp` file.

Comment: [Preprocessor - Directives](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor) _"...The preprocessing directives control the behavior of the preprocessor. Each directive occupies one line and has the following format: * the `#` character..."_

Comment: The content of the included file itself is not a preprocessor directive except if it also contains # directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the statements with the symbol # are known as preprocessor directive

> ```
> # include "example.cpp" // Does it count as preprocessor directive
> ```

Yes, it is a preprocessor directive. This line starts with `#`.